# Norm of the sum of inverse matrices

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B$ be two invertible matrices. Is there a way to compute $\|A^{-1} -B^{-1}\|$ in terms of $\|A-B\|$?

Comment: If $A,B$ commute it is easy.

Comment: The world would be sooo much nicer if matrices commuted.. :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an induced norm: $||A^{-1}-B^{-1}||=||A^{-1}(A-B)B^{-1}||\leq ||A^{-1}||||B^{-1}||||A-B||$. Of course to think about a bound not using $||A^{-1}||$ and $||B^{-1}||$ is hopeless. For instance, have a look on the case $n=1$.